# Wrap content, including text with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have content that looks something like this:

```
<div id='container'>
.
.
.
 <div id='fromHere'>...</div>
  foo<br />
  bar<br />
  <div class='etc">
   ...
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to wrap the contents of #container, after #fromHere in a div something like this:

```
<div id='container'>
.
.
.
 <div id='fromHere'>...</div>
  <div id='newDiv'>
   foo<br />
   bar<br />
   <div class='etc">
    ...
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I guess I could do it with string manipulation like [6962614](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962614/jquery-how-to-wrap-from-tag-to-tag-including-text-nodes-in-a-div) but this has to be reusable so I'd prefer to use JQuery selectors if possible.

Comment: Could you to try to explain what you are trying to do a little clearer? Can you not directly edit the HTML? Is all your trying to do wrap all content after #fromHere div in a new div?

Comment: The html is generated dynamically by a CMS so I can't edit it directly. I've tried to simplify something here that is quite complex, but, basically, I can only manipulate content within #container. I need to do a whole bunch of find and replace stuff and then rewrite .html(). Trouble is that the javascript I'm using is contained within #fromHere so I have to work on everything that follows it without overwriting the script itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/), [`.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/), [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) and [`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/):

```
var $elements = $("#container").contents();
$elements
  .slice($elements.index($('#fromHere')) + 1)
  .wrapAll('<div id="newDiv"></div>');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6pabd/)

This gets all the child nodes of `#container`, determines the index of `#fromHere` among its siblings, gets all following siblings and wraps them in a new element.

Comment: That seems to be working - neat. +1 for now and I'll give it a good workout later